# python: tarfile extraction error IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename

Tags: python, tarfile

I'm extracting a file using tarfile. Unfortunately this compressed file came from a linux server, and contains several files that contain illegal Windows OS characters for files (':').

I'm using the below:

```
extract = tarfile.open(file)
extract.extractall(path=new_path)
extract.close()
```

I get the following error:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: ... "file::ext"

So I tried passing the error with:

```
try:
    extract = tarfile.open(file)
    extract.extractall(path=new_path)
    extract.close()
except IOError:
    pass
```

That does work, however the extraction does not continue. It just stops with this failure.

When I extract the archive with WinRAR, the file is automatically renamed to "file__ext".

Is there a WinRAR extension to python? Or maybe a way to skip the error and continue the extraction? Or automatically rename the file like WinRAR does. I don't mind if the file will be skipped.

I saw several posts with this error, however all of them were for compressing, not extracting.

Comment: Does your filename contains colons ?

Comment: The compressed file itself, no. A few files inside the file, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extract = tarfile.open(file)
for f in extract:
    # add other unsavory characters in the brackets
    f.name = re.sub(r'[:]', '_', f.name)
extract.extractall(path=new_path)
extract.close()
```

(Changes won't be saved to the original file b/c we're opening it in read mode by default.)

Comment: For a reason I can't identify, your answer does not work. However it did lead me to the correct path in resolution, so I marked it as the solution. I eventually used maketrans() and f.name = f.name.translate() from the string library instead of the regex. Thanks!

Comment: Odd. I tested it in both python 2 and 3. Glad you found your solution, though!

Answer (score 0):

If the main goal is to batch these jobs, you can just call winRAR from the command line:

> import subprocess
>   subprocess.call(['winRAR.exe', 'x', 'file.rar', 'PathToExtractTo'], shell=True)

I haven't tested the above code, but hopefully it provides some ideas.